# Transferring 100,000 images to S3. What's the quickest way?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm looking for the fastest way to transfer ~100,000 images from a server to my Amazon S3 bucket.

Would that be to loop through every image and do a separate PUT request? I was hoping there was a quicker way, but haven't found anything.

Comment: @Robert Massaioli FTP is not supported in S3.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe try the snail mail?

[Amazon Import/Export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/)

Answer (score 2):

[s3funnel](https://github.com/sstoiana/s3funnel). I used this last week to transfer around 3,000,000 images to S3. It is multi-threaded, so tends to be very fast. I tested a number of commercial and open-source tools, and s3funnel is by far the best IMO.

Comment: I don't see a way to point s3funnel at a directory - did you manually have to construct a list of your 3,000,000 files?

Comment: I haven't used s3funnel for a while - the awscli tool now has S3 sync options, so I have been using that instead.

Comment: IIRC correctly, I only needed to transfer files to the root of the bucket in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with S3, but if there is no bulk upload tool, you can maybe speed things up by looping over your images in multiple parallel processes, until you max out your network connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Image Uploader](http://image-uploader-docs.aurigma.com/Docs/ImageUploader/UploadingtoCloudStorage.htm) batch upload control. Or if this is a one-time task I consider using some [Amazon sample](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=2263&categoryID=47).

Anyway, if you want to use PUT/POST request for uploading, one file per request - is Amazon's API restriction and it seems to me there's nothing to be done.

Answer (score 0):

We ( CloudOpt ) built a solution to optimize data transfer into Amazon S3 called CloudOptimizer. It uses symmetric deduplication, compression, and a bunch of other techniques. Take a look and let me know what you think. I would love to get your feedback.

http://www.cloudopt.com